# How can I return customized error in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling

When I use do.. try.. catch.. print(error) for SQL select, error return example:

sqlError(notice: Notice(
localizedSeverity: ERROR
severity: ERROR
code: 42601
message: syntax error at or near "selectt"
position: 1
file: scan.l
line: 1128
routine: scanner_yyerror
))

Is there any way to just get a message? "syntax error at or near "selectt""

Comment: You have to either `catch` cast (with `as`) the error to whatever type that's returned, and then access its `message` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't share the `Error` definitions, but let us assume it was something like:

```swift
struct Notice {
    let severity: Severity
    let code: Int
    let message: String
    ...
}

enum DatabaseError: Error {
    case sqlError(notice: Notice)
}
```

Then, you might catch the `Notice` associated with this `sqlError` like so:

```swift
do {
    try foo()
} catch DatabaseError.sqlError(let notice) {
    print(notice.message)                     // syntax error at or near "selectt"
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```